# Implementation of the method .setStyleClass in detail View sapui5

Tags: css, sapui5

Is there a possibility to adjust my table design with the method .setStyleClass?
And where and how do I implement this method ? Below a part of my detail view :

```
<columns>

                    <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>detailLineItemTableIDColumn}"/>
                    </Column>

                    <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>detailLineItemTableUnitNumberColumn}"/>

                    </Column>

                    <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>detailLineItemTableUoMColumn}"/>
                    </Column>


                    <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>detailLineItemTableDate}"/>
                    </Column>
                sap.m.Column.setStyleClass
            </columns>
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem>
                    <cells>

                        <ObjectAttribute
                                text="{Matnr}"
                                />
                        <ObjectNumber
                                number="{path: 'Gesme' , formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit',formatOptions: {showMeasure: false}}" unit="{Meins}" state="Error"/>
                        <ObjectAttribute
                                text="{Lgpla}"/>
                        <ObjectAttribute
                                text="{path: 'Bdatu', formatter: '.formatter.formatDate'}"/>
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
```

I want to adjust the font size of the column names. Feel free to suggest smarter ideas than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using XML views and in order to add custom style sheets in XML view you don't need to use addStyleClass but just add **class** attribute to the element that you want to add style to.

Let's assume that you have a button you need to add style in the following way:

```
<Button class="myStyleClass"></Button>
```

and **myStyleClass** needs to be exist in your css file:

```
.myStyleClass {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: (1) I created an external css file 
(2) included it in the component.js with jQuery.sap.includeStyleSheet
(3) wrote my css method:     .myStyleTable{
                                              font-size: 200%;
                                              }
(4) <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" class="myStyleTable">
      <Text text="{i18n>detailLineItemTableIDColumn}"/>
      </Column>

Why did my font size not changed ?
Regards Felix

Comment: Probably because it didn't apply to the actual DOM elements for were after. You can easily track that down in dev tools but you might to read a little bit on how css is applied in general, search terms 'cascade', 'specificity', 'inheritance'